# how to redirect the link to other page rather then default in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

[image]

Perhaps this is the code that linking a default page:

```
<?php if($ct_options['ct_link_title'] == 'Yes') { ?>
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<?php } else { ?>
<h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
<?php } ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

I want to display a page that I build in page-builder instead of default page

Please advise. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: What do you mean by custom link? Something like `http://customwebsite.com/index.php/services/My-First-Service-test/`

Comment: @RajuDawadi I updated my question. please check

Comment: Then don't use permalink. just use `<h4><a href="https://google.com/"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4><br>` Hope I understood it correct.

Comment: but there is not one link. I have 6 different link and e.g. tomorrow may be 1 thousand links how will I deal them?

Comment: Use custom fields for each post and set default as `the_permalink()` that could be best option.

Comment: I am working in wordpress and one file with name of loop-services.php controlling it. how can I even use custom fields?

Comment: Isn't that for posts loop?

Comment: you can say but its for page to display services with brief description

Comment: In that case, I suggest you to use Advance custom field plugin. [link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) . And use custom field with repeater.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97550/discussion-between-lifesaver-and-raju-dawadi).

Comment: @HungryMind I installed it but you also seen via teamviewer there is no option to fix it. any other way

Comment: Am I missing something here? this post has been given 2 points... but it's really unclear to me. what is $ct_options? Sounds like a plugin.. THis isn't workpress out of the box.

Comment: @LifeSaver using custom permalink plugin could do that in your case. Set custom permalink to the services to the page you want to target.

Comment: Let's continue discussion on chat [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97550/discussion-between-lifesaver-and-raju-dawadi)

Comment: How can I chat with you?

Comment: On this [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97550/discussion-between-lifesaver-and-raju-dawadi) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install plugin ACF in your wordpress and follow this [TUTORIAL](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-field-group/)

If you still have any problem let me know

**Update:**
If you are not easy with this plugin then I'll strongly recommend another very easy plugin "Redirection".

Just copy paste source and target URL's and you are done

[image]

Comment: I installed it successfully but don't know how to use it for that purpose

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorial I referred to?

Comment: Yes but still unable to do it